# How to concatenate git history from one branch to another?

Tags: git, github

I screwed up.

When I created a new branch I deleted everything on purpose (including the .git folder). This was intentional, I wanted to rewrite my project in a different framework and had no need for the original code (deleting .git was not intentional).

Now when I submit a PR of my new branch to master, GitHub shows this message:

> There isn’t anything to compare.
>
> **master** and **new_branch** are entirely different commit histories.

Makes sense, since I deleted `.git`.

More so, if I `git log` inside of `new_branch` the history starts when I restarted the project, not when I initially created the repository.

Is there a way for me to concatenate the git history of my `master` branch to the beginning of my `new_branch`?

Comment: Create another new branch from master and this time don't delete the .git?

Comment: Is there a way for me to automatically import the commit history of my new branch into this new branch?

Comment: So - do you have another copy of the Git repository that you're fetching/pulling from (i.e. a remote)? Where is the **master** branch coming from?

Comment: The remote for the master and my new branch are hosted on GitHub? Not sure if this answers your question @user31601

Comment: Yes it does. 1 more question though: how many commits do you currently have on **new_branch**?

Comment: 12 commits @user31601

Comment: OK, and does your current local repository contain the complete original **master** branch? (run `git checkout master && git log` to see)

Comment: @user31601 It has everything up until the point where I created my new branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create another new branch in your local repository, from the existing master branch:

   ```
   git checkout master && git branch new_new_branch
   ```
2. Switch to the new branch you just created, and merge **new_branch** into it:

   ```
   git checkout new_new_branch && git merge --allow-unrelated-histories new_branch
   ```
3. **new_new_branch** Should now contain the entire history of **master** followed by the history of **new_branch**. It's head commit/state should be the same as that of **new_branch**. GitHub should allow you to submit a PR for **new_new_branch** back to **master** in another repository.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I received this message upon the last command: 

merge: new_branch - not something we can merge

Did you mean this?
 origin/master

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/maxchehab/Bulldog-Bucks This is the repository. The branch in question is `flutter`.